# Apache Web Server Configuration to install Owncloud 8.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2, owncloud-server

I'm trying to install ownCloud server and I did the first steps ok, using the instructions of the manual. Now it's time to configure Apache web server.

Please look to the extract of the installation manual below.

My point is how to create the owncloud.conf file. I tried to do it using the graphical interface of Ubuntu, but I guess that I should to it using the terminal. What commands should I use in the terminal?

Apache Web Server Configuration¶
On Debian, Ubuntu, and their derivatives, Apache installs with a useful configuration so all you have to do is create a /etc/apache2/sites-available/owncloud.conf file with these lines in it, replacing the Directory and other filepaths with your own filepaths:

Options +FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride All

Dav off

SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/owncloud
 SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/owncloud

If you install ownCloud outside of Apache’s DocumentRoot, then you must add an Alias directive at the top of the file. In this example ownCloud is installed in /var/www/owncloud:

Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/"
Then create a symlink to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

Comment: You can also use graphical tools to navigate to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, then "File" -> "Create Document" -> "Empty File" and name it as needed. Then use gedit, kate, leafpad or any other texteditor of you choice, which should be suggested by right-clicking on the newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but answering.

You can use `nano` or `pico` from the terminal to make a new file. 
For example,

`sudo nano owncloud.conf`

will open a new blank file with name "owncloud.conf". To save the changes to the file use `Ctrl+X` then you will be prompted for save changes. Pressing `y` or `n` does the job.

Keyboard shortcuts for nano: [Keyboard short-cuts](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/sedwards/Nano/NanoKeyboardCommands.html)

More details about nano :  [Manpage for `nano`](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.1.html)

To open an existing file: 
`nano /path/to/file/filename`

**About owncloud**: It is suggested to upgrade to newer version.